# is this a convex optimization problem?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Can someone clarify is this a convex optimization problem or not.

$min \| X-UV\|_{F}\quad $  s.t $ \quad U \geq ,V\geq0$  .

If not , what makes the problem non-convex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nonconvex. Trivial way to show this is to consider the scalar case, and then simply study two points, and a point in-between. For instance, when $X=1$ two optimal solutions with objective value $0$ are $(1,1)$ and $(2,1/2)$. What is the objective value of the point in the middle of these solutions?